# MobX not updating React view when pushing to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mobx, mobx-react

My Store.js:

```
import { observable, useStrict, action } from 'mobx';

useStrict(true);

export const state = observable({

    contacts: []

});

export const actions = {

    addContact: action((firstName, lastName) => {
        state.contacts.push({
            id: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1),
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName
        });
    })

};
```

My index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { state, actions } from './Store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider state={state} actions={actions}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ContactList from './components/ContactList';
import ContactAdder from './components/ContactAdder';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

const App = inject('state', 'actions')(observer(class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <h1>Contacts</h1>

        <ContactList
          contacts={this.props.state.contacts}
          onDelete={this.props.actions.removeContact}
        />

        <ContactAdder onAdd={this.props.actions.addContact} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}));

export default App;
```

And finally my ContactAdder.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ContactAdder extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='ContactAdder'>
                <input type='text' value='' placeholder='First Name' />
                <input type='text' value='' placeholder='Last Name' />
                <button onClick={this.props.onAdd.bind(this, 'Test', 'Testerson')}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ContactAdder;
```

After `addContact()` runs in `Store.js` I can see, when I do a console log, that the array does get mutated. But for some reason my view isn't reacting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're actually updating the state of a component that renders.

Comment: @Cruiser I was under the impression that MobX does that for you. If you have an "observable" value that changes, any class that is an "observer" would re-render. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: I think the MobX docs might help: https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html I think you're changing values outside of a tracked function, which doesn't work. Look at the part of the page with this heading: Incorrect: changing a non-observable reference

Comment: I've not used MobX in prod so just trying to sort out possibilities with you

Comment: What does your `ContactList` look like? Without seeing the component, I would guess that it will work if you make that one into an `observer` as well

Comment: @Tholle that was the issue! You can set this as the answer and I'll accept if you want... So I was under the impression that since the contacts are getting sent to ContactList as props that ContactList would automatically re-render. Setting ContactList to also be an observer solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your `ContactList` component, I think the issue would be resolved if you just make that into an `observer` as well.

An observer component will re-render once the observables that got de-referenced in the previous render are changed. The `this.props.state.contacts` does not de-reference your contacts array. It would work if you wrote `this.props.state.contacts.slice()` or `this.props.state.contacts.peek()`, but that is generally only used when [**passing observables to external libraries**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html).

You might just as well make all your components that use observables into `observers` to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
<ContactList
  contacts={this.props.state.contacts.toJS()}
  onDelete={this.props.actions.removeContact}
/>
```

Try to use the `toJS()` method for `state.contacts` to convert ObservableArray to Array, then it will update the ContactList.